# В svgator не работает programmatic старт

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animation

Svg скачиваю по всем правилам, выбрав "Programmatic". Пробовала как "embedded", встроенный в svg плеер, так и "external"

Странность - загружаю свой svg в Live Demo на странице [svgator-player-js-api](https://www.svgator.com/help/getting-started/svgator-player-js-api) и оно не загружется (крутит загрузку до бесконечности)

В консоли была ошибка TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firefoxsample'), эту проблему решило [удаление некоторых расширений из chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76697631/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-firefoxsample)

Но теперь в консоли написано TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'play'). Плюс само ide ругается на svgatorPlayer, пишет, что такого не знает

Кусочек моего кода

```
$('path[data-district^="CFO"]').on( 'mouseenter', function () {
      $('#main').css( 'opacity', '0');
      $('#CFO').addClass('show-info');
      document.getElementById("CFO").svgatorPlayer.play();
})
```

И jade

```
.list__diagram_info
  object#CFO( type="image/svg+xml", data="assets/data/images/animated/round/info/round-CFO.svg" )
```

Наводим мы на элемент карты, отрисованной через svg при загрузке страницы

```
  $.each(regions, function (index, data) {
     var newpath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
     newpath.setAttribute("id", data.id);
     newpath.setAttribute("d", data.path);
     newpath.setAttribute("data-title", data.text);
     newpath.setAttribute("data-district", data.federalDistrict);
     newpath.setAttribute("stroke", '#ebf1f6');
     newpath.setAttribute("stroke-width", '.4');
     newpath.setAttribute("fill", "#0272B0");
        
     document.getElementById("map_index__svg").appendChild(newpath);
  });
```

Я пробовала все варианты доступа к API svgator, в том числе [с официального сайта](https://www.svgator.com/help/getting-started/animate-programmatically). Ничего не меняется

Уже два дня с этим сражаюсь, может кто-то сталкивался?